# How do I take a time-lapse on a Nikon D7100?

Tags: nikon, timelapse, nikon-d7100, self-timer, shot-to-shot-time

How can I take a time-lapse of more than ten shots on my Nikon D7100?

Comment: Page 145 of your manual would be a good place to start.  What have you tried in those steps that you are wondering about?

Comment: @dpollitt I'm wondering how to set up my camera to take 1 picture every second for two hours.

Comment: I'm not sure how page 145 of your manual does not answer this question still. Please explain what actual problem you are stuck on.

Comment: @dpollitt Silly me! I just realized that you can make the number of shots more than ten by moving the dial. whoops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper link to know exactly to take a timelapse with `D7100`

**http://www.dummies.com/photography/cameras/nikon-camera/automatic-time-lapse-photography-on-your-nikon-d7100/**

Comment: that is not an answer to the question

Comment: Welcome to Photography! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: See also this Meta.SE question: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I read this three times not having a clue. But the forth time, it worked.